# in an app, how to swich between access points without loosing connection?

Tags: android, wifimanager

Trying to connect to same SSID, but different BSSID (same WiFi, different access point). Now, if I disconnect and reconnect, why do I still have to find the best signal? By default, it will connect to best signal (closest) access point. How can I connect to best signal without disconnecting and reconnecting?

I'm using wifimanager to find my network and my access points. I can find all my access points and their BSSID and their signal level. Now, in order to connect to best signal, I need to disconnect and reconnect, this will make my app to loose connection for a while, until reconnects.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ScanResult scan_wifi_results : wifiList) {
                if (scan_wifi_results.SSID.equals("Office")||scan_wifi_results.SSID.equals("Warehouse")) {
                    if (bestSignal == null || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, scan_wifi_results.level) < 0) { bestSignal = scan_wifi_results; }
                    deviceList.add(scan_wifi_results.SSID + " - db: " + scan_wifi_results.level + " - Mac: " + scan_wifi_results.BSSID); }
            }
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.wifi_template, deviceList.toArray());
            wifiDeviceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
            WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
            config.SSID = bestSignal.SSID;
            config.BSSID = bestSignal.BSSID;
            netID = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
        }
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netID,true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        Toast.makeText(context,"Connected to best Signal: " + bestSignal.BSSID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

if I add wifiManager.enableNetwork(netID,true) without disconnect and reconnect, it will not change access point
Is possible to accomplish that without loosing wifi connection?